# Targeting elements that are not direct children in HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I am using Chartist.js for some charts and I need to target some elements inside the chart in order to generate some elements that are related to them. Is there a way to target such deeply nested child elements inside the "chart1". I need to target the "g" elements with the classes of "ct-series-a", "ct-series-b", etc... But since there are multiple charts on the page that ALSO have elements with these class names, I need to only target the ones that are contained in the chart with the id of "chart1".

HTML Mock-up

```
<div id="chart1" class="ct-chart">
<svg>
<g>
<g class="ct-series ct-series-a"></g>
<g class="ct-series ct-series-b"></g>
<g class="ct-series ct-series-c"></g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this should help you.

```js
const chart1 = document.getElementById("chart1");
const seriesA = chart1.getElementsByClassName("ct-series-a")[0]
console.log(seriesA.className)
// I did use className , for reducing console data to show u the result in console .
```

```html
<div id="chart1" class="ct-chart">
  <svg>
    <g>
      <g class="ct-series ct-series-a"></g>
      <g class="ct-series ct-series-b"></g>
      <g class="ct-series ct-series-c"></g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```